# Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to send an email with sap commerce.
I have well configured the **`local.properties`** of the config extension

```
mail.smtp.server=smtp.gmail.com

mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.from=sapcommerce14@gmail.com
mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

mail.smtp.user=sapcommerce14@gmail.com
mail.smtp.password=********

mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

but after the execution of the job and when sending the email a warning is displayed

> e-mail is sent to sourour siala
>
> from email page : sapcommerce14@gmail.com
>
> DiscountNotificationEmailContext init
>
> INFO  [TaskExecutor-master-21338-ProcessTask [8796928541622]] [GenerateEmailAction] Email message generated
>
> INFO  [TaskExecutor-master-21341-ProcessTask [8796928574390]] [DefaultEmailService] Sending Email [8796294879296] To [[sourour.siala@enis.tn]] From [sapcommerce14@gmail.com] Subject [Exclusive Promotions on Our Products - Don't Miss Out!!  ]
>
> WARN  [TaskExecutor-master-21341-ProcessTask [8796928574390]] [DefaultEmailService] Could not send e-mail pk [8796294879296] subject [Exclusive Promotions on Our Products - Don't Miss Out!!
> ] cause: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

Here are the steps of my work

1. I created a "ListFavoritesProcess" model  extends "StoreFrontCustomerProcess" with one attribute

   ```
   <attribute qualifier="products" type="ProductList">
    <persistence type="property" />
    <description>Attribute contains the products that will be used in the process</description>
   </attribute>
   ```
2. then I created the process.xml file
3. then I created a class to start the process

   ```
   public Boolean discountNotificationEmailprocess(final CustomerModel customer, final Set<ProductModel> products)
   {
   Boolean bool = false;
   if ((customer != null) && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(products))
   {
       final ListFavoritesProcessModel listFavoritesProcessModel = getBusinessProcessService()
        .createProcess("listFavoritesProcessModel-" + customer.getUid() + "-"System.currentTimeMillis() + "-"+ Thread.currentThread().getId(), "DiscountNotificationEmailProcess");
   listFavoritesProcessModel.setCustomer(customer);
            listFavoritesProcessModel.setStore(getBaseStoreService().getBaseStoreForUid("electronics"));
            listFavoritesProcessModel.setSite(getBaseSiteService().getBaseSiteForUID("electronics"));
            listFavoritesProcessModel.setLanguage(getBaseStoreService().getBaseStoreForUid("electronics").getDefaultLanguage());
            listFavoritesProcessModel.setCurrency(getBaseStoreService().getBaseStoreForUid("electronics").getDefaultCurrency());
   listFavoritesProcessModel.setProducts(new ArrayList<ProductModel>(products));
   getModelService().save(listFavoritesProcessModel);
   getBusinessProcessService().startProcess(listFavoritesProcessModel);
   bool = true;
   }
   return bool;
   }
   ```
4. then I created the context which extends from AbstractEmailContext<ListFavoritesProcessModel>

   ```
   @Override
   public void init(final ListFavoritesProcessModel listFavoritesProcessModel, final EmailPageModel emailPageModel)
   {
   super.init(listFavoritesProcessModel, emailPageModel);
   products = new ArrayList<>();
   final List<ProductModel> productsModel = listFavoritesProcessModel.getProducts();
   productsModel.forEach(productModel -> {
   final ProductData productData = getProductFacade().getProductForOptions(productModel,
   Arrays.asList(ProductOption.BASIC, ProductOption.PRICE, ProductOption.STOCK, ProductOption.PROMOTIONS));
   products.add(productData);
   });
   put(EMAIL, getCustomerEmailResolutionService().getEmailForCustomer(getCustomer(listFavoritesProcessModel)));
   put(DISPLAY_NAME, listFavoritesProcessModel.getCustomer().getName());
   put(FROM_EMAIL, Config.getParameter("mail.smtp.user"));
   put(FROM_DISPLAY_NAME, "sap");
   System.out.println("DiscountNotificationEmailContext init");
   }
   ```

Comment: Is that the password for the gmail account?  or an apps password?  is there any more to the error message?

Comment: No it's not my password. I recovered the password from the gmail account from the "Application passwords" section.
About the error, it just displays this warning in the console, no error

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

Sometimes, Google will disable access to less secure or other apps to protect your account from potential vulnerabilities. This setting can be turned off, or two factor authentication can be enabled for the account `(recommended)`.

**Resolution**

`In most cases the issue can be resolved by setting up two-step verification on Google.`

Enable two-step verification for the account via this link : Google Two Steps Verification.

Generate a specific password via this link : Google Specific Passwords.

Use the generated specific password in configuration below:
mail.smtp.password=<"generated specific password">

See Also

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636795778044562052-2774445042&rd=2#cantsignin

Alternate way to test email functionality locally:

https://groundlevelhybris.wordpress.com/2020/03/20/email-not-getting-triggered-in-hybris-local-environment/

Comment: I tried this option and tested sending email with groovy in hac and it worked. but when I use the email process in hybris, there is always this warning.

Comment: please share full stack trace of the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, trying to send email messages from my Hybris / SAP Commerce Cloud platform, using a local SMTP server as relay.

Error message was  :
Could not send e-mail pk [1234567788999] subject [mysubject] cause: Sending the email to the following server failed : mysmtpserver.com:25

The error was caused by the special character '#' (hash sign) in the password.
I had to reset the password for the mail relay account without the # character and it worked.

Hope this can help.
Regards,